# Cheapest/Easiest Server capable of hosting ASP.NET websites

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

I want to setup my own server at my house that is capable of running ASP.net pages and SQL databases for development testing purposes. I want it to be a dedicated server (not just running on my development PC) So what is the cheapest/easiest/fastest server I could buy for this purpose?
I know I could just buy a separate PC, put a cheap copy of XP on it and use IIS and SQL Server Express . Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will just be using this for your own development purposes, then yes a cheap pc will run fine, IIS and SQL with a single user are not particularly demanding.

One thing to ensure is that your development environment is as similar as possible to where you will be deploying. If your going to be deploying to IIS 7 or 6, then using Windows XP on your test server is no good, as it only has IIS 5 etc.

Finally, using XP has some limitations, you can only have 1 website in IIS and a maximum of 10 concurrent connections, so if you want to run multiple sites, you need a different OS.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is slightly off-tag (you mentioned "AND sql-server"), but you might want to think about the possibility of running a non-Windows server (slightly cheaper) and putting [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) on it.

However, as @Sam mentions, this does have a big disadvantage in that it is not the same environment as the likely "production" server.